# Uncaught ReferenceError: child is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

- i am new to react.
- i am workig on accordion.
- i am trying to convert from es5 to es6 react.createcomponent
- can you guys tell me why i am facing the below error
  Uncaught ReferenceError: child is not defined
- providing code below

```or-tag-here
class Accordion extends React.Component {
```

Accordion>

```
      </div>
), document.getElementById('example'));
```

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory (and has nothing to do with React): You are accessing `child.props.id`, but you haven't defined `child` anywhere. I can only guess you meant `enhanceSection` to have a *parameter* `child`? I.e. `enhanceSection(child) { ... }`.

Comment: @FelixKling hey I updated the code here http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/56/ but still I am not getting accordion like this http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/41/  now I dont see any error too...can you help me

Comment: Lots of little problems - variables used without being defined, for the most part. I've cleared the errors: http://jsfiddle.net/4gzhw2v5/ - but no idea what you're actually aiming for. I strongly recommend using a JS linter, like ES Lint, it will help identify these kinds of issues.

Comment: @Toby hey did you paste wrong fiddle... still I am seeing the same error in the console...I am trying to build something similar to this jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/41

Comment: Apparently I did, aapologies: http://jsfiddle.net/4xhfhb4v/

Comment: @Toby yeah error went away but still why I am not able to see the accordion like this http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/41/    . can you help me

Comment: If you can tell me the specific problem you're having, perhaps. I can't tell you why two completely different blocks of code work in completely different ways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142861/discussion-between-texi-rv-and-toby).

Comment: @FelixKling hey its not calling  this function any idea ??  i debugged gave debuggers here but still not able to find it http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/64/ onSelect(id) {
        console.log("onSelect");

Comment: @Toby  hey its not calling  this function any idea ??  i debugged gave debuggers here but still not able to find it http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/64/ onSelect(id) {
        console.log("onSelect");